# SQL query to get only rows match the condition based on two separated columns under one 'group by'

Tags: sql, sql-server

The simple SELECT query would return the data as below:

Select ID, User, Country, TimeLogged from Data

```
ID     User      Country   TimeLogged
1      Samantha  SCO       10
1      John      UK         5
1      Andrew    NZL       15
2      John      UK        20
3      Mark      UK        10
3      Mark      UK        20
3      Steven    UK        10
3      Andrew    NZL       15
3      Sharon    IRL        5
4      Andrew    NZL       25
4      Michael   AUS        5
5      Jessica   USA       30
```

I would like to return a sum of time logged for each user grouped by ID
But for only ID numbers where both of these values `Country = UK` and `User = Andrew` are included within their rows.

So the output in the above example would be

```
ID     User      Country   TimeLogged
1      John      UK         5
1      Andrew    NZL       15
3      Mark      UK        30
3      Steven    UK        10
3      Andrew    NZL       15
```

Comment: Start with adding a `WHERE` clause, to only include rows where country is UK, or user is Andrew.

Comment: If you want "only ID numbers where the pair of these fields Country = UK and User = Andrew" how is it that you have rows in your expected results where Country <> UK and User <> Andrew?

Comment: Isaac - the OP described his logic incorrectly. I think he means OR rather than AND

Comment: @iainc, Re-read OP's requirements. Only return ID's that include both `Country = 'UK' AND User = 'Andrew'`. Not on the same row, but grouped by ID.

Comment: I read OP's requirements .OP's results table contradicts OP's logic. If Andrew and UK then ID 3 Andrew NZL would not be there.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to identify which IDs you're going to be returning

```
SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE Country='UK' 
INTERSECT
SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE [User]='Andrew';
```

and based on that, you can then filter to aggregate the expected rows.

```
SELECT ID, 
       [User], 
       Country, 
       SUM(Timelogged) as Timelogged 
FROM mytable
WHERE (Country='UK' OR [User]='Andrew')
AND ID IN(  SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE Country='UK' 
            INTERSECT
            SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE [User]='Andrew')
GROUP BY ID, [User], country;
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm. Never used INTERSECT so something new I've learnt.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have described what you need to write almost perfectly but not quite. Your result table indicates that you want Country = UK OR User = Andrew, rather than AND

You need to select and group by, then include a WHERE:-

```
Select ID, User, Country, SUM(Timelogged) as Timelogged from mytable
WHERE Country='UK' OR User='Andrew'
Group by ID, user, country
```

Comment: Re-read OP's requirements. This query would return `ID = 4  Andrew` which is not what OP wanted, because `ID = 4` does not contain `Country = UK`

Comment: Neither does ID =3 contain Country UK but that is in the OP's results table.

Comment: But ID = 3 has Andrew. It's confusing, but it's an implied `AND` grouping by `ID`.